# Problem with 'Sort exceeded memory limit' MongoDb in Spring

Tags: java, database, mongodb, spring-boot, criteria

I'm writing a method to implement a query using MongoRepository, I'm using aggregation in a Java/Spring project, but it is giving exceeded memory limit when I'm testing.

I've tried use

```
newAggregationOptions().cursorBatchSize(pageable.getPageSize()).allowDiskUse(true).build()
```

but didn't work

my method:

```
...
        var matchCriteria = match(criteria);

        var unwindVariations = unwind("variations", false);


        var sort = sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "variations.plataformStatus.status");

        var countResult = count().as("totalElements");
        var aggregationOptions = Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().cursorBatchSize(pageable.getPageSize()).allowDiskUse(true).build();

        var countAggregation = newAggregation(
                matchCriteria,
                unwindVariations,
                sort,
                countResult)
                .withOptions(aggregationOptions);

        var totalElements = mongoTemplate.aggregate(countAggregation, "PRODUCT", Map.class).getMappedResults();
```

error message:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16819 (Location16819): 'Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.' on server cluster0-shard-00-01-du380.mongodb.net:27017.
```

Comment: Could you identify if the Exception is thrown in the first or second aggregation operation?

Comment: I've corrected the post, only a first aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable **allowDiskUse** option.

By default, sort operation has a 100MB limit (in memory), enabling that option in your operation will allow to use bigger size.

From [MongoDB's sort documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-memory-limit):

> The $sort stage has a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. By default, if the stage exceeds this limit, $sort will produce an error. To allow for the handling of large datasets, set the allowDiskUse option to true to enable $sort operations to write to temporary files.

Comment: I've tried use

```newAggregationOptions().cursorBatchSize(pageable.getPageSize()).allowDiskUse(true).build()``` What's wrong? is already enable